# How to concat the fields in one Property

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have list of properties. like

```
public string name {get;set;}
public string lastname {get;set;}
public string age {get;set;}
public string fullName {get;set;}
```

Now what I want to do is concat the first 3 properties in the last `'FullName'` property.

Means if I have `name = John, Lastname = smith, age = 20`

then

```
Fullname should be John Smith 20
```

How can I do that. Should I do that in `Domain Class` with the help of `setter property` or Can I do that with using `Linq.`

I have more than 1000 records which is brought in `IEnumerable`  . How can I do that. I want to avoid looping the records.

Comment: It's not clear what the last two paragraphs are about. Where does LINQ come into this at all, or "looping the records"? If you want to display multiple records, you'll obviously have to have a loop somewhere (possibly implicit) - but that seems completely separate from property concatenation...

Comment: You already have a property defined, just define it with a `getter` and mark it as not mapped and then `return name + " " + LastName + " " + age`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would make it a *read-only* property instead - unless you want to start having to parse the value into bits when it's set. So:

```
public string FullName
{
    // This is assuming you've also fixed the property names to be conventional
    // I'd also suggest changing "Name" to "GivenName" or "FirstName".
    get { return string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", Name, LastName, Age); }
}
```

If you *really* want to have a setter, I would suggest splitting the input by spaces and then setting each of the three other properties. *Don't* have separate storage for the `FullName` property (an independent field) as otherwise the data can become inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

```
public string FullName
{
    get 
    { 
        return name + " " + lastname + " " + age.ToString();
    }
}
```

Or

```
public string FullName
{
    get 
    { 
        return string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", name, lastname, age);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not answering the question directly since it's already been answered, however you may find this useful.

You could also override the ToString method inside the class.

```
public override string ToString()
{
     return string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", Name, LastName, Age);
}
```

One of the benefits is during debugging where you are examining an IEnumerable, you can see the underlying data at a glance without having to drill into each individual item.

Answer (score 0):

Define the property with just a getter:

```
public string FullName
{
    get
    {
        return String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", this.Name, this.LastName, this.Age);
    }
}
```